# Por que a palavra "embora" não é utilizada no seu sentido original?

Tags: ortografia, significado, etimologia, conjunções

Embora é uma contração das palavras "**em boa hora**", usada no sentido de ir a algum lugar ou como conjunção com o sentido de "**apesar de**".

- Qual o sentido de "em boa hora"? Ir a alguma lugar em boa hora?

Por que a palavra embora não é utilizada no seu sentido original?

Comment: Muitas palavras perdem seu significado original com o tempo.  Palavras nascem, palavras morrem, outras mudam o significado.  Se pudéssemos conversar com falantes da língua portuguêsa de 7 séculos atrás, não entenderíamos uma palavra.

Comment: Em concordância com @Centaurus, toda língua é uma construção coletiva que é dinâmica, ao invés de estática, e é ressignificada infinitesimalmente a cada novo falante que se apropria dela.  Nesse sentido, podemos interpretar todas as formas de registro da língua que tenham cunho normativo como fotografias do estado atual dessa construção.

Answer (score 5):

[Há certa discussão etimológica a respeito da palavra](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/embora/). Aparentemente os dicionários de língua portuguesa não concordam entre eles.

[Neste artigo, a questão é explicada em detalhes](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-evolucao-do-significado-de-embora-adverbio-conjuncao/28185). Aparentemente, o emprego de "embora" como **conjunção concessiva** parte da mesma ideia da etimologia original, que seria o afastamento entre elementos. Ou seja, essa semântica de contraponto serviu para dar um novo sentido à palavra. A conjunção concessiva serviria como afastamento de argumentos.

Answer (score 4):

Deixo aqui a opinião de Said Ali na *Gramática Histórica da Língua Portuguêsa* (1921), aqui transcrita com a ortografia revista para a edição (brasileira) de 1964:

### Significado original

> 944. Pôsto que a instituição dos oráculos e agouros estivesse morta desde muito tempo, perdurou na era medieval, e ainda na idade moderna, a crença de que o êxito dos atos humanos dependia da hora em que eram empreendidos. Daí o costume de se acrescentar a frases optativas ou imperativas, por sinceridade, ou mera cortesia, a locução *em boa hora*. Se dominava a má vontade para com outrem, e convinha manifestá-la, recorria-se, pelo contrário, ao agouro *em hora má*.
> 945. [omitido; sobre *em hora má* e a sua transformação em *eramá*, *ieramá*, *aramá* e *amará*]
> 946. O agouro benevolente enunciado pela fórmula *em boa hora* entende-se claramente de passos como os seguintes:
>
>      > <sub>Vaamos *em bora hora* nosso caminho (Zurara, *Guiné* 337) — Que dissesse *em boa hora* o que lhe aprouvesse (*ib*. 186) — Venhaes *em boa hora*... e nam perdoeis a minhas orelhas, porque já entendo ao que vindes; avezado sou a ouvir cousas que me dão pena (Arrais 555)</sub>
> 947. Fundiu o uso as três palavras em uma só, *embora*, sendo adotada sem o mínimo de escrúpulo pela linguagem literária. Deixando em silêncio, por desnecessários, outros muitos exemplos de escritores antigos e modernos, mencionarei apenas isto de Vieira: *Vay-te embora, ou na má hora* (*Serm.* 1, 208)

### Ideia de afastamento

> 948. Tornou-se usual acompanhar a forma imperativa de *ir* e *vir* dos votos de bom êxito. Esta noção, compreendida no advérbio *embora*, desluziu-se da consciência hodierna, que confusamente descarrega nêle o conceito de “afastamento”, como se os verbos não dissessem já a mesma cousa. Com êste critério, e desconhecendo-se o sentido que outrora teve o advérbio *embora*, torna-se ininteligível o seu emprêgo junto a verbos que denotam repouso, v. g. em Vieira, *Serm.* 11, 422:
>
>      > <sub>Queria Christo introduzir o Sacramento, e lançar fora o cordeiro da Ley, e para isso permittio que o cordeiro estivesse *embora* na mesma mesa com o Sacramento: que desta maneira se desterram com suavidade as sombras das leys velhas… Estejão agora juntos o Sacramento e do Cordeiro, que amanhã ir fora o cordeiro e ficará o Sacramento.</sub>

### Como conjunção concessiva

> 949. Não se usou êste advérbio sòmente para augurar bem ou desejar hora propícia às emprêsas humanas. Introduziu-se também em orações optativas e outras para denotar que se concede a possibilidade do fato, ou que o indivíduo que fala não se opõe ao seu cumprimento. Da alteração semântica dão testemunho os seguintes passos:
>
>      > <sub>Ria *embora* quem quizer, que eu em meu siso estou (Gil Vicente) — Respondeu por vezes que morressem *muito embora*, que melhor era morrerem cá que no sertão, porque morriam baptizados (Vieira, _Cartas 1, 118) — O que está mais longe perca-se *embora* (_ibl 1, 463) — As promessas do premio dilatem-se *embora* (Vieira, *Serm.* 2, 395) — Honrem-se *embora* com estas arvores os seus montes, que os nossos valles não hão mister quem procure a sua exaltação (*ib.* 5, 360) — Mate-me *embora*, comtanto que seja imperador (*ib.* 5, 466) — Mas Francisco Xavier, venha-lhe *embora* a tentação dormindo, que dormindo e acordado, sempre está seguro (_ib. 8, 104)</sub>
> 950. Desta prática veio o transforma-se, em português hodierno, o advérbio *embora* em conjunção concessiva, mudando-se naturalmente a contextura das orações. A principal passou a servir de subordinada, e a correlata despe-se da partícula *que*, convertendo-se em principal, dizendo-se  v. g.: *embora honrem essas árvores os seus montes, os nossos values não hão mister quem procure a sua exaltação*. Em Filinto Elísio 14, XIX já se encontra: *embora cumpra o traductor com esses tres deveres*.

Comment: Quem é que iria suspeitar uma coisa destas!

Answer (score -3):

> A palavra "embora" tem sua origem na locução "em boa hora" (Vá-se
>   "embora"). Três radicais se aglutinaram, concorrendo para a sua
>   formação. É o mesmo que ocorre com "fidalgo", na origem "filho
>   d'alikon", o quinhão sagrado da terra, entre os muçulmanos. "Fonseca"
>   vem de "fonte seca"; "morcego", de "rato (mur) cego".

Então como foi citado ai em cima, eu acho que não tem explicações concretas já que simplesmente pegaram algumas palavras, juntaram, e por algum motivo, deram um significado totalmente diferente.

Comment: Começou **mesmo** bem com a as primeiras 3 frases. Depois descarrilou...